# OpenCV, Android: Detect change in direction of object

Tags: android, opencv

I want to detect the change in direction of a ball, for example, the ball is falling and once it hits the ground it bounces, the direction changed from DOWN to UP, is there a way to detect this change in direction using OpenCV in an android application?

Comment: I'm  sorry for too obviously answer, but you need recognize ball on ***sequence of pictures***, find center/etc. and calc it's speed. When speed changed it's sign - ball changed direction. Provide more information and maybe you receive more reliable answer.